# How to get the same display on desktop, tablet, and mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, display

I'm building a webpage for a client that I inherited from another developer. The link is: http://up8.431.myftpupload.com/. The client would like the phone number and the social icons in the top bar to display in the same style across all devices:desktop, tablet, and mobile. She doesn't like how when the display gets small enough the phone number and social icons stack on top of each other. That's fine but if there's no room to display them left and right but if there is, she would like to keep the same style. Problem is, I can't figure out how to make that happen.

Upon inspecting the element, I notice that each block has a width of auto, or whatever it needs to fit in. I've tried giving each block a display:inline rule in the hopes that they would take on the content width and align left to right and then I can just float the social icons to the right.

Tried something like this:

```
#top-bar-content, #top-bar-social
{
display:inline;
}
```

AND

```
.top-bar-left, #top-bar-right
{
display:inline;
}
```

What I hoped would happen is both blocks would display inline, back to back and I could just float them left and right respectively. What actually happened is the phone numbers changed its width to fit the content and floated itself to the left exactly how i wanted it to. The social block however, did not. It lost its dimensions; upon inspecting the element I find its width and height are 0x0. It remained in the same spot. Like I said, in my head I expected it to adopt its content width and sit right next to the phone number.

I'm sure this is just a noob error and I'm just not seeing what's in front of me. I really appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Use the browser inspector, you'll see that `top-bar-content` and `top-bar-social` as `float: left` and `float: right` but on smaller screens there are media queries that change it to `float: none`, remove those lines on your CSS file and you are done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the parent div that contains both the number and social icons to display:flex. Then add justify-content:space-evenly or space-around or space-between (experiment between them) to the same parent element.

So you will have to use a media query to apply this for mobile devices only. When this is applied on desktop devices there is some interference from other classes and "::after" pesudo code.

```
#top-bar-inner {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

This will do the trick

Comment: Thank you this worked great! I haven't coded in a long time and the justify-content is new to me. I will have to learn some more about it.

Comment: Yeah flex and grid have made css really easy to do worth the hour or so to bunker down and learn about it